# Deleting Multiple workbooks Same sheet by name by selecting a folder

Tags: excel, vba

Deleting multiple workbooks same sheet by name but below code is not working it does not perform any action after selecting the folder.

```
Sub jdghd()
Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As String
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
   
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
Do While xFileName <> ""

  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)

  For Each sht In wbk.Sheets
    If sht.Name = Summary Then
      wbk.Worksheets(Summary).Delete
    End If
  Next

  wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True

  xFileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `Dir` initially to get the first file. `Do While myFile <> ""`  - this won't loop because `MyFile` is a blank string.

Comment: Apologies i did not get you i corrected the  xFileName = Dir

Comment: Before the loop, add `xFileName  = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xlsx")` or whatever your extension is.

Comment: its working now but after completion the job it gives debug to this line   Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName) and when i open the files the sheet with summary name was still available

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Sorry we could not find the Z:\Z folder\Name\. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Comment: seem like its looking for Z into Z, try taking it off

Comment: Z is drive and i have folder in my drive and there are 15 files in folder.

Comment: I got it thank you so much for your help guys.